# Can Multiple WSO2 API manager integrate with single WSO2IS-KM 5.7.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We have installed WSO2 IS-KM version 5.7.0 and we want to integrate Multiple WSO2 API Manager version 2.6.0 with WSO2 IS-KM. 
 Requesting you to please suggest and share the link to configure multiple WSO2 API manager with WSO2 IS-KM version 5.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Please find a simple set of configurations on setting up multiple API Manager nodes with a single IS as Key Manager. It is required to front the API Manager nodes with a load balancer (with sticky sessions enabled & data-sources are shared among all the nodes) and configure the API Manager nodes as follows

API Manager Nodes: api-manager.xml (assumption IS-KM port offset 1, therefore 9444)

```
<AuthManager>
  <!-- Server URL of the Authentication service -->
  <ServerURL>https://localhost:9444/services/</ServerURL>
  ...
</AuthManager>
...
<APIKeyValidator>
  <!-- Server URL of the API key manager -->
  <ServerURL>https://localhost:9444/services/</ServerURL>
  ...
</APIKeyValidator>
```

IS Key Manager Node: api-manager.xml

```
<APIGateway>
  <Environments>
    <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
      ...
      <!-- Server URL of the API gateway -->
      <ServerURL>https://loadbalancer/services/</ServerURL>
      ...
</APIGateway>
```

Sample NGINX

```
upstream mgtnode {
  server localhost:9443; # api manager node 01
  server localhost:9443; # api manager node 02
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name mgtgw.am.wso2.com;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
  ...
  location / {
    ...
    proxy_pass https://mgtnode;
  }
}
```

References

- [Configuring IS as Key Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager)